# Definiteness of quadratic form subject to linear constraint

Tags: multivariable-calculus, quadratic-forms

[image]

I have three questions related to the definition given in the image above:

1. Why do we only have a restriction $q\neq0$? Shouldn't we place the same restriction on p as well?
2. Is there a condition for a quadratic semidefinite form subject to a linear constraint?
3. This may be related to the second question: what happens if the determinant is zero?

Comment: What are the author and the title of the book you've quoted from, and the page number, please?

Comment: @RosieF This is Sydsaeter and Hammond (Mathematics for Economic Analysis), pg 530.